# omnios install to USB stick or SD card

Tags: solaris

I am building out a NAS and wanted to try using a Solaris derivative instead of FreeBSD for my ZFS shares.  My other NAS devices have FreeNAS installed onto a USB stick, which is nice because it leaves all the data drives available for storage.

I've read conflicting stories about installing other Solaris derivatives onto a flash drive.  It appears the "minimal" install is pretty large, and the OS continues to use the install drive for some kind of cache/swap state, which dramatically reduces the expected lifespan of the stick. OmniOS seems to be a lot more oriented to the embedded crowd though.

With FreeNAS, the OS takes an entire disk so the USB/SD drive is most practical.  Is that the case with OmniOS?  Or can I just have a 32G partition on my data disks for the OS and use the rest of the disk for storage?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For this case is `SmartOS` better choice. It is Solais derivate, that runs completely from USB stick and local disks zpool just store your data, nothing from OS. Upgrades are way you just copy new image to USB stick. `SmartOS` is primary a hypervisor, but all other features are there too + relatively fresh prebuilt packages repo available.

[>SmartOS<](http://smartos.org)

Btw when you want full featured storage appliance and no problem for you to install appliance SW on disks, then `NexentaStor` is definitely your choice. Comparable with FreeNAS... but much more features. You can even make fiber channel storage device from your old PC... just click out on web GUI.

[>NexentaStor<](http://nexentastor.org/)

Answer (score -1):

I would go with the real Oracle Solaris 11.1 rather than a derivative distro. You can check [the license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/solaris-cluster-express-license-167852.html) to see if it fits your needs without paying. Basically you are free (free of cost) to use Oracle Solaris for "developing, testing, prototyping and demonstrating".

On the [Oracle Solaris 11.1 download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/index.html) you can find USB Install Images. There's a chicken-and-egg dependency with the 'usbcopy' utility (the utility you need to copy the image onto the USB stick). You can find a solution [here](http://www.maslik.com/How-to-create-Live-USB-with-Solaris-11.1-under-Windows-7-machine).

I believe this is by far your easiest option.